# Scala: Any way to force a trait to return a certain type while permitting any arguments?

Tags: scala

I have lots of `process` functions that must all return the same type, e.g. `List[(String, Int)]`. These different functions all take different arguments, but I need to combine their outputs. So is there a way of using the type system - probably via a trait - to guarantee that all of my `process` functions will return the same type?

E.g.:

```
object ProcessData1 {
    def process(input: String): List[(String, Int)] = ???
}


object ProcessData2 {
    def process(input: Seq[String], flag: Boolean): List[(String, Int)] = ???
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with parameterized types.

```
// Input is a type variable. Could also be "A" or any other type identifier
trait Processor[Input] {
  def process(input: Input): List[(String, Int)]
}

// This defines Input = String for this class
object ProcessData1 extends Processor[String] {
  def process(input: String): List[(String, Int)] = ???
}

// Note the tupling
object ProcessData2 extends Processor[(Seq[String], Boolean)] {
  def process(rawInput: (Seq[String], Boolean)): List[(String, Int)] = {
    val (input, flag) = rawInput
    ???
  }
}
```

Unfortunately they must all have the same function arity, but you can work around that by tupling the arguments you'd like it to have, as in ProcessData2